# how to access the grand parent method in PHP

Tags: php, inheritance

I have implemented multilevel inheritance with the following three classes.
If I want to access the show() method of p class in r class then how we can do that.
I have tried with parent::parent::show() but no such facility available in PHP.

So, can anyone suggest how we can do that?

```
class p{
    public function show() {
        echo __method__;
    }
}

class q extends p {
    public function show() {
        echo __method__;
    }
}

class r extends q {
    public function show() {
        echo __method__;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wanting to do this sounds like a design problem.  If a class extends a class - it should do it for a reason and so wanting to skip this functionality is avoiding some processing which could be important.

Comment: you're trying to bypass chain of command :) technically r needs to talk to q to talk to p

Answer (score 0):

Use `parent::method_name()` to call parent method

```
class p{
    public function show() {
        echo "I am from p class";
    }
}

class q extends p {
    public function show() {
        parent::show();
    }
}

class r extends q {
    public function show() {
        parent::show();
    }
}
```

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

when you extend a class, the subclass inherits all of the public and protected methods from the parent class. Unless a class overrides those methods, they will retain their original functionality.
use different method name like

```
class p{

    public function show() {
        echo __method__;
    }

    public function p_show() {
        echo __method__;
    }
}

class q extends p {

     public function show() {
       echo __method__;
     }

    public function q_show() {
       echo __method__;
     }
}

class r extends q {

  public function show() {
    echo __method__;
  }

}

$testObject = new r();
$testObject->p_show();
$testObject->q_show();
$testObject->show();
```

output:

```
p::p_show
q::q_show
r::show
```

Answer (score 0):

Each parent may have their own implementation of the function so you could create an other function that indicate parent or parent of parent:

```
class p
{
    public function show()
    {
        return 'hello grandson';
    }
}

class q extends p
{
    public function show()
    {
        return 'hello child';
    }

    public function showFather()
    {
        return Parent::show();
    }
}

class r extends q
{
    public function show()
    {
        return 'Hello';
    }

    public function showFather()
    {
        return Parent::show();
    }

    public function showGrandFather()
    {
        return Parent::showFather();
    }
}

$instance = new r();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object of class p in class r and then can access show method. like this:

```
class p{
    public function show() {
        echo __method__;
    }
}

class q extends p {
    public function show() {
        echo __method__;
    }
}

class r extends q {
    public function show() {
        echo __method__;
    }

    public function showP() {
        $p = new p();
        $p->show();

    }

}

$r = new r();
echo $r->showP();
```

Hope it helps you.